# "If / Then" statement not working

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to perform an `If` statement so that, if a variable's value is equal to `"Mils"`, it will do the stated function. But nothing is currently happening.

What am I doing wrong?

```
z = Sheet2.range("B20").value
If z = "Mils" Then
    Set cx = Sheet8.range("D3", Sheet8.range("D3").End(xlDown))
    For Each rng In cx
        rng.value = rng.value / y
    Next rng
    Set cy = Sheet8.range("E3", Sheet8.range("E3").End(xlDown))
    For Each rngy In cy
        rngy.value = rngy.value / y
    Next rngy
End If
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `z = Sheet2.range` line and step through the code, what do you see happening? What is the value of `z` when it reaches the `If z = "Mils" Then` line? What happens when you keep stepping through the code?

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand

Comment: Put the cursor on the `z = ` line and hit F9.  When the code runs and reaches that point, it will stop. Hit F8 to execute that line of code; it will stop again. Look to see what `z` contains, then hit F8 again to execute the line `If z =`. It will stop again. Hit F8 to continue to step through the code, and see where it goes next.

Comment: How many sheets do you have? If it's more than two, maybe try `z = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B20").Value`, as `Sheet2` is not *necessarily* the same as `Sheets("Sheet2")`.  Also, to be technical, are you looking to see if the cell has `Mils` or `"Mils"` (i.e. with quotes or without quotes?)

Comment: If you have the Immediate Window active (CTRL+G) you can use a line like `Debug.Print z` just before your line `If z = "Mils" Then`. This will print the value of z to the console so you can see what the value of z is. You will still need to step through your code (as others have suggested) but `Debug.Print` can be a lifesaver when you are getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i am reading, your program probably **ignored** some of your instructions.

try this problem solving method:

1) hover your cursor over and click the code.

```
If z = "Mils" Then
```

2) click F9 to put a mark on that line

3) click the F8 key progressively ( what this key does is it runs the program till that code. so it basically shows you the flow of your program.)

4) check if F8 skipped any of your codes in :

```
If z = "Mils" Then
    Set cx = Sheet8.range("D3", Sheet8.range("D3").End(xlDown))
    For Each rng In cx
        rng.value = rng.value / y
    Next rng
    Set cy = Sheet8.range("E3", Sheet8.range("E3").End(xlDown))
    For Each rngy In cy
        rngy.value = rngy.value / y
    Next rngy
End If
```

if it skipped any steps then you should probably take a look at the skipped steps and make necessary adjustments.

Comment: Minor issue - "hover your cursor over" - you actually have to click on the line before you press F9, otherwise the current line will end up with the breakpoint instead of the one your mouse is hovering over.  (P.S. You can also click in the border area to the left of the line, thus saving a keystroke - but I have to admit that that gets a bit hard to describe to someone new to debugging.)

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by the code is 'ignoring' instructions. I have never seen code 'ignore' instructions, but I have seen cases where users think their 'If' statement should evaluate to True, when it evaluates to false, and as a result the code doesn't run the lines inside the if block (which is expected).